# Android WebView - Is it possible to intercept target="_blank" links

Tags: android, android-webview

How can i let my WebView intercept links ONLY if they have target="_blank" set?

I am aware of the shouldOverrideUrlLoading() method, but that does not give me the info, if the link had target="_blank" set. The problem is, with the url alone i am not able to distinguish the links, i want to intercept. I need to know, if target="_blank" was set.

Is there a way? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to see a solution to check the `target="_blank"` too, but I think, this is not possible (unless maybe with some nasty JavaScript injection hack)

It's much simpler to attach an extra parameter (e.g. `?oib=1`) to the URL and check it in `shouldOverrideUrlLoading`:

```
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    if (url.contains("oib=1")) {
        view.getContext().startActivity(
                new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

To do this, you need control over the links of course. If you have many such links, you can write a JavaScript function that does the work for you:

```
jQuery('a[target="_blank"]').attr('href', function(i, h) { 
    return h + (h.indexOf('?') != -1 ? '&oib=1' : '?oib=1');
});
```

Comment: Wouldn't that be a nasty Javascript injection hack, too? ;)  But i actually like the idea, will try it.

Comment: Interesting, I did not thought of executing the Javascript part above as injection code in the android app. But I think that would work (and would indeed be a nasty JS injection hack, yes).